# Send FCM message to open deeplink in my android application by Laravel

Tags: laravel, firebase-cloud-messaging, deep-linking, deeplink, android-deep-link

How can i send Firebase cloud token to my android app to open my app deeplink?

I implemented deeplink and its worked

Then config my firebase FCM and my laravel send notification to my android device. with this library

https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM

i cant find any method to send link but

```
 function sendNotification($user_id, $type)
 {
     $message = getNotificationMessage($type);

     try {
        $fcm_tokens = ClientInfo::where('user_id', $user_id)->all();
        foreach ($fcm_tokens as $key => $fcm_token) {
        $optionBuilder = new OptionsBuilder();
        $optionBuilder->setTimeToLive(60 * 20);

        $notificationBuilder = new PayloadNotificationBuilder();
        $notificationBuilder->setBody($message)
            ->setSound('default')
            ->setClickAction('bazarshahr://customer.app/order');

        $dataBuilder = new PayloadDataBuilder();
        $dataBuilder->addData(['deeplink' => 'bazarshahr://customer.app/product/39']);

        $option = $optionBuilder->build();
        $notification = $notificationBuilder->build();
        $data = $dataBuilder->build();

        $token = $fcm_token['firebase_token'];

        $downstreamResponse = FCM::sendTo($token, $option, $notification, $data);

        $downstreamResponse->numberSuccess();
        $downstreamResponse->numberFailure();
        $downstreamResponse->numberModification();

        // return Array - you must remove all this tokens in your database
        $downstreamResponse->tokensToDelete();

        // return Array (key : oldToken, value : new token - you must change the token in your database)
        $downstreamResponse->tokensToModify();

        // return Array - you should try to resend the message to the tokens in the array
        $downstreamResponse->tokensToRetry();

        // return Array (key:token, value:error) - in production you should remove from your database the tokens
        $downstreamResponse->tokensWithError();
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    SystemLog::error(sprintf("[helpers.sendNotif] Can't send Nofication: %s (%d)", $e->getMessage(), $e->getCode()));
    return false;
}

return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this question? thanks.

Comment: i added answer here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is not mentioned in Fcm documentation **but** i tried some sort of tests on my own and figured out the solution: as we replied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63203361/308578)

Instead of *click_action* we need to put *link*:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key={SERVER_KEY}

{
 "to" : "{Firebase client token}",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification"
     "link": "example://my.app/products"  <<-- Here is the solution
 }
}
```