# Open deep link url when click on Fcm notification

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, deep-linking

I'm using Google's `Fcm` to send notification to my **Android** client

I want to open specific screen with Deep Link url eg. `example://my.app/products`

Here is endpoint to send notification using REST api

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key={SERVER_KEY}

{
 "to" : "{Firebase client token}",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification"
     "click_action": "example://my.app/products"
 }
}
```

This request sends notification to my specified client, but does not open Deep Link, when clicking on push nothing happens

Is there a way to open Deep Link from Fcm Push ?

Answer (score 12):

This feature is not mentioned in Fcm documentation **but** i tried some sort of tests on my own and figured out the solution:

Instead of *click_action* we need to put *link*:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key={SERVER_KEY}

{
 "to" : "{Firebase client token}",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification"
     "link": "example://my.app/products"  <<-- Here is the solution
 }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solutions, but I got
```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"link\" at 'message.android.notification': Cannot find field.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
           ....
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: @DarioScoppelletti what is your request data ?

Comment: The request data is: {
  "notification" : {
     "body" : "Message Text",
  },
  "android" : {
     "priority" : "NORMAL",
     "notification" : {
        "sound" : "default",
        "channel_id" : "channel_id",
        "link" : "app://www.myapp.app/path/path"
     }
  },
  "token" : "device_token"
}
Thanks

Comment: @DarioScoppelletti You should put "link" part in outer "notification" object, are you using legacy api `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` ?

Comment: I am using the latest API `POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/{parent=projects/*}/messages:send`. However now I am using another way: FCM send an only data message and the App forward it as a local notification, thus Deep Linking of Navigation Component works. Thanks - Dario Scoppelletti

Comment: @DarioScoppelletti so, Firebase itself doesn't support opening deeplinks when a user pressed on a notification, do I understand it right?

Comment: @OlegYablokov. Yes, I still use my solution from Dec 21, 2020. I don't know if anything has changed since then.

Comment: @DarioScoppelletti this seems to be android specific. I have a react native app and I also need to embed the deep link in the firebase cloud message. How can I make it work for both iOS and android?

Comment: @VictorCui Sorry, but I don't know React Native

Comment: any luck guys with new fcm api?

Answer (score 1):

Note: if you actually want to open a page in your app when the user clicks on a notification, [refer to this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications#handling-interaction).

*I post it as an answer because I tried to implement opening a page in my app and thought deep links would help but it is probably not the best solution.*