# Redirect to a specific screen from React Native Firebase Push Notifications based on a Deeplink

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, notifications, deep-linking

I got a problem,

1 ) I'm using Firebase to send remote Push Notifications, i test by sending from FCM tester.

2 ) I've activated Deep-Linking in my project and started to use it.

3 ) In FCM tester i pass this key value into "notifications.data" :

> { "link" : "MY_LINK" }

Now i want my app to be able to recognize there is a deepLink in it & read it.
Which i achieved to do somehow but not the way i was looking for.

What i did :

NotificationContextProvider.ts

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribeClosedApp = messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(
      remoteMessage => {
        addNotification(remoteMessage);
        console.log(
          'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
          remoteMessage.notification,
        );
        redirectFromKey(remoteMessage.data?.redirection);
        console.log(remoteMessage.data, 'remote message data');
        console.log(remoteMessage, 'remote message full');
        console.log(remoteMessage.notification?.body, 'remote message body');
        console.log(remoteMessage.notification?.title, 'remote message title');
        if (remoteMessage.data?.link === 'https://[MY-LINK]/TnRV') {
          console.log(remoteMessage.data?.link, 'Deeplink detected & opened');
          navigation.navigate({
            name: 'Logged',
            params: {
              screen: 'Onboarded',
              params: {
                screen: 'LastAnalyse',
              },
            },
          });
        }
      },
    );
```

And it's working fine but it's not based on reading a link, but by comparing a value and it's not what i'm trying to achieve.

Firebase Doc' give us a way to do this : https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage#listening-for-dynamic-links

This is what Firebase suggests :

```
import dynamicLinks from '@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links';

function App() {
  const handleDynamicLink = link => {
    // Handle dynamic link inside your own application
    if (link.url === 'https://invertase.io/offer') {
      // ...navigate to your offers screen
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = dynamicLinks().onLink(handleDynamicLink);
    // When the component is unmounted, remove the listener
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return null;
}
```

And i have no clue how to make it works.
I got to mention that deep-links are correctly setup in my project and working fine, my code is in Typescript.

Basicaly you can find on this web page what i'm trying to achieve but i want to use Firebase/messaging + Dynamic links. My project don't use local notifications and will never do : https://medium.com/tribalscale/working-with-react-navigation-v5-firebase-cloud-messaging-and-firebase-dynamic-links-7d5c817d50aa

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into this earlier, it seems that...

- You can't send a deep link in an FCM message using the firebase `Compose Notification` UI.
- You probably can send a deep link in an FCM message using the [FCM REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref). More in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63203360/open-deep-link-url-when-click-on-fcm-notification/63203361#63203361).

The REST API looks so cumbersome to implement you're probably better off the way you're doing it: Using the firebase message composer with a little data payload, and your app parses the message data with Invertase [messaging](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage) methods `firebase.messaging().getInitialNotification()` and `firebase.messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp()`.

As for deep linking, which your users might create in-app when trying to share something, or you might create in the firebase Dynamic Links UI: For your app to notice actual deep links being tapped on the device, you can use Invertase [dynamic links](https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage) methods `firebase.dynamicLinks().getInitialLink()` and `firebase.dynamicLinks().onLink()`.